# Android Camera.open sometimes fails

Tags: android, exception, camera, android-camera

I am using parts of the [android vision barcode-reader sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader) to read QR-codes. Occasionally (like 2 in 500 Users) I'm getting a Firebase Crash report, which happens at Camera.open.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:678) 
at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:520) 
at mobilevision.CameraSource.createCamera(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.access$2200(CameraSource.java:0) 
at mobilevision.CameraSource.release(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.start(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.getIdForRequestedCamera(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.selectSizePair(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.generateValidPreviewSizeList(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.selectPreviewFpsRange(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.setRotation(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.createPreviewBuffer(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.access$102(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.access$202(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.access$302(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.access$502(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.access$802(CameraSource.java:0) 
at <OR>.access$1800(CameraSource.java:0) 
at mobilevision.CameraSourcePreview.startIfReady(CameraSourcePreview.java:0) 
at mobilevision.CameraSourcePreview.start(CameraSourcePreview.java:0) 
at <OR>.start(CameraSourcePreview.java:0) 
at <OR>.stop(CameraSourcePreview.java:0) 
at <OR>.access$102(CameraSourcePreview.java:0) 
at <OR>.access$200(CameraSourcePreview.java:0) 
at mobilevision.CameraSourcePreview$SurfaceCallback.surfaceCreated(CameraSourcePreview.java:0) 
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:679) 
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:206) 
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944) 
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2432) 
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1328) 
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6730) 
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894) 
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696) 
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631) 
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:0) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Code part where exception is thrown:

```
int requestedCameraId = getIdForRequestedCamera(mFacing);
if (requestedCameraId == -1) {
  throw new Exception("Could not find requested camera.");
}

Camera camera = Camera.open(requestedCameraId);
```

I'm asking for the camera permission similarly as it is implemented in the barcode-reader sample. Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce this exact exception.
But I was able to reproduce a similar exception when running the app in an emulator without camera (both cameras set to none). But since this exception happens in real devices, I'm wondering what might be the cause.
Phones in the crash report are e.g. Galaxy J1(2016) (j1x3g) with A5.1, Plume P6 Pro LTE (PGN528) with A6.0, 3600i (CP3600I) with A6.0.

Can anybody give me a hint on how to reproduce this exception or even better, does anybody know the reason why it is not possible to start a camera even though the permission is granted?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's my pleasure to answer your question.

There are corresponding checkPermission () methods, but these methods only determine whether the permissions have been registered in the manifest file. The user's actions are not accessible.

```
PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
int permission = packageManager.checkPermission("android.permission.CAMERA", "your packageName");
if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == permission) {
   // you can do something
} else {
   // request permission
}
```

So how do we detect permissions in the system below 6.0?
The present method is the use of `try{} catch){}` way:

```
public boolean isCameraCanUse() {
    boolean isCanUse = true;
    Camera mCamera = null;
    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters mParameters = mCamera.getParameters(); //针对魅族手机
        mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isCanUse = false;
    }

    if (mCamera != null) {
        try {
            mCamera.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return isCanUse;
        }
    }
    return isCanUse;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'm already using checkPermission, and getting this error for API Level 21, 22 and 23. 
Furthermore, in API Level 21 you can always access the camera because the user can not deny permissions or am I missing something?